# Search query in sqlite3 database for certain items

Tags: c++, sqlite

I have a list of items as an string array in C++. I also have a sqlite3 database which contains blacklisted strings. Now I must Use the list of items that i have to mark them with 0 or 1, telling me if they are blacklisted or not. I could do search for them one by one by using "Select * from ITEMS_TABLE WHERE item = string[i]" but it will take time. I could also pull blacklist from database and then look for them in my list. But is there an efficient way to find out which of the items in my list are blacklisted.

Lets say I have following structure

```
struct item 
{ 
    char name[MAX_NAME_LEN]; 
    bool isBlacklisted; 
};
```

Then i use array of these structures to knows if any of them is blacklisted. So i have to make isBlacklisted flag to true, if the entry is found in database. If i use Select approach, it returns me list of items that were blacklisted. But i still need to find them in my array using string comparisons. Is there some efficient way to do is. Does database provide any such functionality.

Thanks and regards,
Mike.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Design your database structure according to your requirements. You want to know blacklist items simply use a column which contains 0 or 1 for blacklist or not i.e your table ITEMS_TABLE has these columns

```
itemcode itemname isblacklist
1        item1    0
2        item2    0
3        item3    1
```

now

```
Select * from ITEMS_TABLE WHERE isblacklist=0
```

this will return non blacklist items and

```
Select * from ITEMS_TABLE WHERE isblacklist=1
```

will return blacklist items, Hope this will help you

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer, This does help me in doing more efficiently but can you please provide solution to the updated problem

Comment: I have a table like this, But i get another list which will contain N items, which may or may not be present in database. So If any of these are present in database, i have to mark then as blacklisted. The database only contains blacklisted items, I will Get items list and scan them which of these items are blacklisted. If I do as you mentioned above, i will get a list of items from db, now i must match this list with the list of N items, where if matches are found the blacklisted flag is set.I just want to avoid string comparisons and see if it can be done by database

Comment: Yes if any thing similar between these two lists you can do that by filtering i.e Select * from ITEMS_TABLE WHERE isblacklist=0 and itemcode <> in (2,4,5)